# Case statements in SQL

Tags: sql

Hello I'm new to SQL and I want to use the Case statement.

I currently have this SQL statement

```
update tblAccount set FullName = rtrim(isnull(FirstName,''));
update tblAccount set FullName = FullName + ' ' + rtrim(MI)
where substring(reverse(MI),1,1)='.';
update tblAccount set FullName = FullName + ' ' + rtrim(MI) + '.'
where substring(reverse(MI),1,1)!='.'
and MI is not null and len(rtrim(MI)) = 1;
update tblAccount set FullName = FullName + ' ' + rtrim(MI) 
where len(rtrim(MI)) >= 2;
update tblAccount set FullName = FullName + ' ' + LastName;
update tblAccount set FullName = FullName + ', ' + Suffix 
where Suffix is not null
and len(rtrim(Suffix)) > 0;
```

I want to convert this into something smaller and more easily readable, I was told a Case statement might help but I'm familar with it, I was wondering if anyone would be able to help convert this into something more readable.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL? The answer may vary depending on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *could* be made into one statement, but because your code re-modifies the same column, you would have to nest and combine function calls and it would be an absolutely huge statement and thus far less readable than your current code.

Also, the order of execution is important, so maintaining and debugging a single statement would be much more difficult.

Leave it as it is. What you have is good.

Regarding performance, may I say that maintenance and clarity of code outweigh performance every time (as long as the performance is "acceptable").

That said, your current calls each require a full table scan, where as a single statement would require only one. However, depending on the size of your table, after the first scan the table may be cached in memory, and the single statement may be so complex that it is actually slower than your current code.

You would have to test it, but you shouldn't consider performance unless there's a problem - don't optimize your code early.

Comment: I was going to say tha same as you, but maintaining and debuggin would be simpler, but how about performance?

Comment: Yup that was what I saw, there are 6 full scans in his statements, instead of just one, i will try to make it by in one statement, let's see how readable it gets xD

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов I had a good look at your question and I can't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: -1 it's not that bad a statement, see my answer. While recommending not to change something is sometimes the best answer indeed, I believe in this case you gave up too quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite it like this, just a little upgrade in performance, But i think it's more  readable in the way that you have it, like @Bohemian said.

```
--MIDDLE NAME?
    update tblAccount 
    set FullName = 
                    case when  substring(reverse(MI),1,1)='.' THEN --  FIRST + SECOND UPDATE
                        rtrim(isnull(FirstName,'')) + ' ' + rtrim(MI)
                    case when substring(reverse(MI),1,1)!='.' and MI is not null and len(rtrim(MI)) = 1 THEN --FIRST AND THIRD UPDATE
                        rtrim(isnull(FirstName,'')) + ' ' + rtrim(MI) + '.'
                    else  -- FIRST UPDATE
                         rtrim(isnull(FirstName,''));
                    end 

    GO      
    -- LASTNAME     
    update tblAccount 
    set FullName = case when len(rtrim(MI)) >= 2 THEN
                        (FullName + ' ' + rtrim(MI)) + ' ' + LastName
                    else
                        FullName + ' ' + LastName;
                    END
    GO

    -- SUFFIX
    update tblAccount 
    set FullName = FullName + ', ' + Suffix 
    where Suffix is not null
    and len(rtrim(Suffix)) > 0;
```

Comment: I agree that the old way is more readable, I was curious into how to use a case statement because I was recommended to do so by my friend.

Comment: this one helps you?, i splitted six updates in 3, for readablity, splitted in steps, I dont think you should split it more what you think @bohemian

Answer (score 0):

The general form is

```
CASE WHEN <condition> THEN <value> ELSE <somethingElse> END
```

Where `WHEN <condition> THEN <value>` can be repeated and `ELSE <somethingElse>` is optional

A case statement can be used a a control structure, as in stored procedures or a script, or inline, as in a `SELECT`.

Your update statements are equivalent to this:

```
UPDATE tblAccount SET FullName = 
    rtrim(isnull(FirstName,''))
    + CASE 
        WHEN substring(reverse(MI),1,1)='.' THEN ' ' + RTRIM(MI)  
            + CASE WHEN where len(rtrim(MI)) >= 2 THEN RTRIM(MI) END
        WHEN MI is not null and len(rtrim(MI)) = 1 THEN rtrim(MI) + '.'
            + CASE WHEN where len(rtrim(MI)) >= 2 THEN RTRIM(MI) END
        ELSE
            + CASE WHEN where len(rtrim(MI)) >= 2 THEN RTRIM(MI) END
    END
    + ' ' + LastName
    + CASE 
        WHEN Suffix IS NOT NULL AND len(rtrim(Suffix)) > 0 THEN ', '+Suffix 
    END
```

You had 6 updates, nrs 1, 5 and 6 are straightforward, they are pretty much copied into the one statement above. Records updates by 2 will not be touched by 3, and 4 can (according to your code, data may prove otherwise) occur with 2, 3 or neither, hence 4's repetition.

---

Naturally, I wholeheartedly disagree with the thesis that your statements are just fine. If what you need is one update, than do one update. And don't give in to the pressure by accepting a non-answer either.

Have fun!

have a look at COALESCE() too, while you're learning.

Comment: You downvoted my answer (meaning it's "not useful")? Consider how *readable* the one-shot statement is, and how hard it would be to add something cross-cutting like correcting capitalization, which in your query would require adding that code to every branch of your case. It just isn't scalable to do it in one go, nor is it a good idea. Just because you *can* do something in code, doesn't meant you *should*

Comment: @Bohemian My point is: just because it's *a little harder*, doesn't mean you shouldn't *try*. See my comment.

As for readability, I don't see any difference between either the original, the other solution, and the one-shot answer, that cannot be solved with whitespace. As for complexity... all  Emre801 needs is to update one column, combining some other, under conditions. The one-shot solution is closer to that, hence less complex.

As for scalability, it wasn't an issue in the question. Is there some meat to your last two statements *'It just isn't scalable'* and *'nor is it a good idea'*?